# With Homebrew opencv appears to be only for python3.10, any chance of getting a version for 3.9?

Tags: python, opencv, homebrew

The current Homebrew formula for opencv contains is dependent on python3.10. This causes the packages to be installed under a python3.10 directory and produces module not found error when attempting to import cv2 with python3.9. Is there any chance of getting this updated for the latest version of python?

Comment: Does this old post help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18961877/18667225 ?

Comment: Using brew info opencv3.9 returns a not found error, brew info opencv39 returns error with suggestion to use opencv which leads to the formula that has the python3.10 dependency but thanks for the idea.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/is-opencv-dependent-on-python3-10/10264

Comment: Homebrew installs packages in usr\local\lib and this is where python has been installed. Can pip be directed to use the same path?